# How to play raw mp3 data in python

Tags: python, mp3

I'm writing an interface that can play music, manipulate playlist, etc using gmusicapi ( https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API ). I've got my application so that it can download the raw mp3 data, but am having a hard time finding a library that will play it. GST can play urls, but doesn't allow cookie auth. pygame can play mp3's, but from file, not data. Does anybody know how do play raw mp3 data in python?

```
def gm_PlaySong(self, url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    for cookie in self.api.session.cookies:
        req.add_header(cookie.name, cookie.value)
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    song = resp.read()
```

song being the raw mp3.

Answer (score 0):

#### Write to File

First, the simple thing you could do is write your mp3 data to a file for pygame to play.  You can do so:

```py
import pygame
def gm_PlaySong(self, url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    for cookie in self.api.session.cookies:
        req.add_header(cookie.name, cookie.value)
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    song = resp.read()
    with open('path/to/file.mp3', 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(song)
    
    pygame.mixer.music.load('path/to/file.mp3')
```

#### Using `StringIO`

Alternatively, something you could dry--and this is a bit of a guess, since I don't have the tools to test it with here--you could try using the [`StringIO.StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO) class to feed your raw mp3 data to pygame similarly to how a Python file object would.

This would look something like this:

```py
import pygame, StringIO
def gm_PlaySong(self, url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    for cookie in self.api.session.cookies:
        req.add_header(cookie.name, cookie.value)
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    song = StringIO.StringIO(resp.read()) # Gives you a file-like object
    
    # load song
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
```

Comment: I'm actually looking into making a streaming app, and don't want to save locally.

Comment: @user1745994, try doing it with the `StringIO` option I've added, then.